# slideToggle is Sliding Multiple Div's Down

Tags: jquery, class, html, slidetoggle

I'm using jQuery's slideToggle on an unordered list in order to make it expand menu items. The problem is that this effect makes all of my div's slide down along with it. How can I make the rest of my document's div's unaffected by slideToggle?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code? Chances are your selector needs changing so it only matches the correct elements.

Comment: I would, but there's a lot of content there...let me see if we can nail it without seeing the code. The selector is correct, and it slides down the correct element but the problem is that when it slides the menu down, like an accordion, the rest of the div's below it also shift down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're actually asking is not very clear from your question. This answer is based on your comment on the question. The reason other elements are pushed down when the hidden element slides down is that that's just the way block elements in HTML work. You will need to change the `position` of your element, for example, to `position: absolute`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/6wqjq/2/) to get you started.

Comment: But I do have a question now, what if I have multiple elements? Like...say I have MAIN MENU -> {SUB MENU ONE, SUBTWO, SUBTHREE}
and for example SUB MENU ONE -> {SUBSUBONE, SUBSUBTWO, SUBSUBTHREE}?

and thus, in some cases i DO want to make some menus slide?